# Icons disappear after saving file Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, 20.04, icons, desktop-icons

**ISSUE**

After saving a text file, some icons and folders on the desktop **disappear**. When you manually refresh screen using ALT-F2, then enter "r", the icons reappear.

**EXAMPLE**

[Open a text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tujcN.jpg)

[Make a change, save, then some desktop icons and files disappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCjYQ.jpg)

[After manual refresh (ALT-F2 > "r") they all reappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0SCH.jpg)

**REMEDIES ATTEMPTED**

`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons` from [Ubuntu 20.04 desktop files and icons missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231994/ubuntu-20-04-desktop-files-and-icons-missing)

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

**SYSTEM DETAILS**

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- TYPE: 64-bit
- GNOME VERSION: 3.36.3
- Windowing System: X11

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a bug with the Desktop extension: this extension is recent and in early development

Comment: This has been reported by [Launchpad Bug #1883174](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons/+bug/1883174).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in Gnome. I found two different reports:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons/+bug/1883174

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons/+bug/1816205

I have both symptoms here. Saving a file in desktop sometimes just flashes the icons but sometimes makes most of them to disappear - but not all of them. And I'm pretty sure the ones that stay on screen are always the same.

There was a proposed fix on 2020.12.07 but I haven't tested it. Will wait.