# Double Desktop icons after installing DESKTOP ICONS NG (DING)

Tags: 20.04, icons, duplicate

i wanted drag/drop option so I installed gnome desktop icon ng extension. But after that i got all my icons duplicated, only one is selectable. I switch the old desktop extension, but it doesn't work. I reboot also...

Any ideas?

Comment: Done, sorry, first time on this forum :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Duplicate desktop icons are because you have both the standard system desktop-icons extension and the DING extension installed at the same time. You need to uninstall this...

`sudo apt purge gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons`

With X11, you may have to restart gnome-shell with ALT+F2 (or ALT+FN+F2), then "r", then ENTER. Or reboot (or logout/login) if you're running Wayland.

Comment: It should be sufficient to just simply disable (turn off) the redundant plugin on the GUI of either _Gnome Tweaks_ or the dedicated app _Extensions_, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Levente No, you can't disable the standard system extension at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/. I can't say about Tweaks or Extensions.

Comment: Then this account on a personal experience may be useful: https://askubuntu.com/a/1328230/1157519

Comment: @Levente Not quite the same problem. If you go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ you'll find that you can disable/enable desktop-icons and it won't make any difference, it still works. I believe that this is because it's one of the three standard **system** gnome-shell extensions, and you won't have enough privs to touch it.

Comment: Are you making this assumption and mounting this argument without actually trying it out either _Extensions_ either _Tweaks_ on your system? (And to offer my findings: yes you can switch it off with _Extensions_. Disabling in _Tweaks_ indeed does not take effect.)

Comment: @Levente No argument here :-) You might be right, if your experience indicates that Extensions will turn it off. As I mention in my first comment, I don't have any direct experience using Extensions to turn if off. The standard https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ won't do it.

Comment: Thank you so much @heynnema now it works :) And as i said in my question, i tried to disabled the extension in tweaks, but it didn't work. So eynnema is the best :-p

Answer (score 0):

right click somewhere on the the desktop, select `Settings` and adjust the screen settings from there:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have both the system desktop icons extension, and the DING extension installed locally: either uninstall the system desktop icons package with:

```
sudo apt purge gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
```

as suggested by the other answer OR remove your local extension with:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com
```

In both cases you will have to restart the gnome-shell after that. **Note**: removing the `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons` package will cause the removal of the `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package. I'm not sure that's a good idea because it *might* lead to problems when upgrading the distro.

In my case, I removed the local extension. Also, this way the (system) extension will be automatically kept up-to-date.