# How did I obtain the "Extensions" app?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell-extension

I'm on stock Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome 3 desktop.

I do have an app that's called "Extensions":

[image: screenshot of the extensions app UI]

I would like to know

- whether it is preinstalled with Ubuntu 20.04

  - in other words, do people mostly have it?
- or did it get installed when I installed the [gnome-shell-extensions package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gnome-shell-extensions) (which is (primarily?) about a collection of actual extensions)

  - so only those have it who also installed this optional package?

I ask this because *Extensions* [seems to take precedence](https://askubuntu.com/a/1328230/1157519) over what is being set in *Gnome Tweaks*' *Extensions* tab.

This makes it difficult to offer definitive help regarding managing gnome shell extensions, since the results seem to depend on the presence of this app.

Answer (score 4):

This is a utility of the Gnome Shell developpers. It's homepage is reported by `apt show` to be https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell. It is a package of the Universe repository, and is not preinstalled. It can be explicitly installed through the package `gnome-shell-extension-prefs`, but it may also be installed along with the official Gnome Shell extensions, `gnome-shell-extension`, for which it is a recommended package. In Ubuntu, `apt` is configured to [install recommended packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18545/installing-suggested-recommended-packages) by default.

Comment: Indeed, I have this package, it is this app. Executing it in the terminal brings up this UI. But I don't have it listed in ( `apt list --manual-installed` | `apt-mark showmanual` ). For this reason I'm still unsure about its origin...

Comment: Also automatically installed indeed for me, so I will update my post at least on that point. I have a strong suspicion that this comes directly from Gnome, but I did not find anything yet (like you ;-)

Comment: I will boot from my live USB and check whether it's there.

Comment: I have written my new hypothesis in my answer.

Comment: In the live USB, the app was not present initially. After adding the `Universe` source, I have run `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions --dry-run` and `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks --dry-run`. I found that `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` has shown up _in both cases_ among the packages that _will be_ installed (according to you, consequence of _recommended_ being enabled by default). So it's not "suggested", it's recommended.

Comment: I updated my answer already, and I used the term "recommended"

Comment: Right, oops, sorry, I did not mean as correcting you, I just meant to emphasize that due to this, it will be installed at this point, and not up to the choice of the user.

Answer (score 2):

As I have learned from [@vanadium's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1329570/1157519), the app is called `gnome-shell-extension-prefs`.

Trying out Ubuntu in a live USB session, the app was not present initially.

After adding the `Universe` source, I have run

- `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions --dry-run` and
- `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks --dry-run`.

I found that `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` has shown up among the packages that *will be* installed in both the case of installing `gnome-tweaks` and installing `gnome-shell-extensions`. (As @vanadium has pointed out, it is because apt is configured by default to install recommended packages.)

From this, it seems safe to assume that anyone who has *Gnome Tweaks* installed, has the *Extensions* app too.

Which is all the more weird, because as I have [found](https://askubuntu.com/a/1328230/1157519), *Extensions* can override *Tweaks*, and at that, without any hint: settings in *Tweaks* will simply not take effect, if they conflict with settings in *Extensions*.

---

Just a detail:

I remember, in the beginning (when I did not have yet `gnome-shell-extensions`), being able to enable/disable the *Desktop Icons* extension with *Tweaks*.

It was only later, at some point in time, that (re-)enabling *Desktop Icons* became impossible through *Tweaks*. (Because then it had to be done with *Extensions*.)

Between these two experiences, I'm aware of two things happening:

- I have installed the `gnome-shell-extensions` package
- I was experimenting with a [`gnome-shell --replace`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1318540/1157519) command, which has disabled all my extensions, and each had to be re-enabled by hand.

Somehow I still think that with the above, I have disqualified myself from reliably assuming how other people's shell extension preferences work...