# Why can't i scroll to the bottom of a document in Gedit?

Tags: gedit

It seems this issue happens any time I open a text file from the file manager or desktop, if gedit opens into a maximized state. When I'm scrolling down, either mouse scroll or dragging the scroll bar, it won't go to the bottom of the document. If I use the arrow keys, the cursor will go down to the unexposed lines and if I type something below what's shown, the lower lines pop up.

Update:
Changing the window by maximizing, minimizing, and even changing to another window and back, will make it scroll properly again.

Comment: This seems to ring a bell for me: as if I might had had experienced something similar; but it was so long ago that I hardly remember the details. In any case, open gedit's preferences, and look into which extensions/plugins are enabled. I would wager that one of the extensions/plugins might be the culprit.

Comment: I turned off the plugins and it still does it. It seems it always does it when i open a file. But unmaximize/maximize makes it function correctly again, it would seem. That's at least a better fix than typing randomly beyond where i can see.

Comment: I just noticed when I switched windows from the browser back to gedit, that also got gedit scrolling correctly. Maybe this is a window management software issue and not gedit's fault.

Comment: Then I would also review which enabled [Gnome shell extensions](https://askubuntu.com/q/1329463) might pose an interference with this...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your window extends beyond the bottom of the page?  I've had similar issues. My environment is xubuntu, which means my screen management is through XFCE.  In that environment, Alt-space will bring up a menu from which you can select resize the window.

Comment: I don't think so, because i can see the info bar at the bottom of the screen. But changing the window in any way does seem to nullify the scrolling problem, until the next time. It's still an issue, if it needs to be fixed every time you use it. But it's better than the previous workaround i was using.