# All desktop icons disappeared from one of my laptops

Tags: 20.04, icons

I am running `Linux 5.8.0-59-generic #66~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 11:14:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`, on two laptops. One of the laptops is fine, but the other laptop has no icons. They were there last night, but this morning they are gone.

The `.desktop` files are, or were, in the `~/Desktop` directory. I removed them and tried putting them back one at a time, but no icons appear.

I've been reading through Ask Ubuntu all morning, but none of the suggestions I found made any difference.

Comment: Do you have the *Desktop Icons* extension enabled? Open the Extensions program, scroll to the bottom and check that the *Desktop Icons* extension is indeed enabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 desktop files and icons missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231994/ubuntu-20-04-desktop-files-and-icons-missing)

Comment: Yes as stated in the Answer I posted, it did solve the problem