# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS not showing icons or anything after power failure during software installation

Tags: 20.04, screen

I was installing some software and suddenly a power failure occurred.  I restarted my system and it is now showing a blank blue screen with two tabs. One of the tabs is my user and the other is trash and when I click on it it is not leading to anywhere.

Comment: A power failure on the wrong split-second can cause severe havoc. You will need to reinstall. You will be able to update your backup from within a live session.

Comment: reboot into `Recovery` then from menu choose root terminal so you can issue the commands to fix the issue

Comment: @ScottStensland Which commands though?

Comment: see  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231994/ubuntu-20-04-desktop-files-and-icons-missing

Comment: Thanks every one. I have re install and issue have been resolved