# Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop files, icons, folders do NOT appear on desktop,

Tags: files, icons, directory

Ubuntu 22.04 Upgraded 20.04 installation. Desktop files, icons, folders do NOT appear on desktop, yet they are in the Desktop folder under Home directory. They will run if I open the Desktop folder and execute them with terminal.

So far everything I have read has not worked to reviel them on the Desktop. They never have shown on the upgraded system from day one.

Comment: Nothing appears in the lower right corner of the desktop?  Which desktop are you running?  Wayland or Xorg at login?  Anything appearing will probably need the "Allow launching" selection from a right mouse click.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 desktop files and icons missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231994/ubuntu-20-04-desktop-files-and-icons-missing)

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue. In my case reinstalling the ubuntu desktop worked:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

After running this, restart the system:

```
sudo reboot
```